# Getting date from string

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to convert a string, for example: "2/5/2014/", into a date that I can use to compare to current date.

Right now I have:

```
private double getTimeAWAY(String sdate) {
    double time=0;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
    Date rdate ; 
       formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
       try {
        rdate = (Date) formatter.parse(sdate);
        time = rdate.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("Time away: ", "it is "+time);
    return time;
}
```

But it crashes when I try this.

The Logcat looks like:

```
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434): Process: com.skateconnect, PID: 3434
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity.getTimeAWAY(AllSpotsActivity.java:259)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity.access$5(AllSpotsActivity.java:253)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.doInBackground(AllSpotsActivity.java:407)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.doInBackground(AllSpotsActivity.java:1)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-04 16:06:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3434):     ... 3 more
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420f8430 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.onPreExecute(AllSpotsActivity.java:333)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$3.onClick(AllSpotsActivity.java:235)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18498)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-04 16:07:00.056: E/WindowManager(3434):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems line 259 is the line making it crash, unless I'm reading the logcat wrong.

Could someone help me out?

Thank you,

Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Date types here with the same short name: `Date`.

One is `java.util.Date`, the other one is `java.sql.Date`.

This is the problem here.

You are getting `java.util.Date` from parse and you are trying to cast it to `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

You got wrong imports. Check Import clause on the top of class code and change `sql.Date` to `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong import, you should use `java.util.Date`